# Debian Sid - Stay some weeks behind current roll

Tags: debian, apt, aptitude, rolling-release

I'm currently on Debian Sid.

Is there a way to only update packages that were released, e.g. at least one week ago? Could I schedule an update and then only upgrade two/four weeks later?

The intent is to make the system a little more stable by rolling in after the most current release set. I haven't had any problems so far, but only by accident / laziness didn't upgrade to the recent systemd issue that affected some of the rolling distros (systemd 240?).

Comment: Sounds to me like you want to use testing instead of unstable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can’t do this after the fact, but you can download a consistent set of updated packages and upgrade to them later:

```
apt update
apt -d upgrade
```

will update the indexes and download all upgrade candidates, without actually performing the upgrade. As long as you don’t update the indexes again (which means not running `apt update` and variants, and also disabling any jobs which might do that for you, such as `apt-daily`), you’ll be able to apply the upgrade later by running

```
apt upgrade
```

If you install `apt-listbugs`, you’ll also be warned about unfixed critical bugs in the versions you’re about to upgrade to before you upgrade.

As [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles) mentioned, it sounds like you might find [Debian testing](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianTesting) more appropriate than unstable. Testing runs a few days behind unstable, and in addition to that, packages only migrate to testing if doing do doesn’t introduce a release-critical bug in testing, and maintains the testing package set coherent (*i.e.*, dependencies are still available etc.). Do note however that there are security implications with running testing and it’s up to you to keep on top of security updates. The linked wiki page has many more details and best practices.

Both Debian testing and Debian unstable aren’t really user-oriented rolling distributions; they’re the staging grounds for the next stable release of Debian.